# Lambda not discarding records from DynamoDB Stream Table if retry attempts is exceed the limit

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a Lambda that attached to the DynamoDB stream. I configured retry attempts upto 5. I have SQS as on failure destination.  In some cases lambda is timing out and It retried upto 5 times. But lambda not discarding records from dynamoDB. It  still remains as its in Table

Answer (score 0):

Lambda would not discard them, why would it....

Lambda is simply a consumer of your stream, if the Lambda fails to process the data, nothing changes in your table, or your stream. The data is still persisted in the table until you remove it, and on the stream for 24 hours.

Comment: Ok. I configured on failure DeadLetter queue. After retry attempts, even its not put any data to the queue. Anything I am missing? I cross checked IAM as well

Comment: That's a different question. I would suggest creating a new post.